# How to Implement Custom List View for the list Items in Android Application

Tags: java, android, listview

I had a problem with the list view having both parent list and the child list of the list activity(implemented through database query). I wish to show them differing their properties by changing the text style (parent list items are in bold, child list items are in normal style).

**I wish to differ with Parentid(Null, NotNull)in their text style(bold, normal) for parent and child items respectively.** Please help me with the code/links. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an [`ExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) would be a way to go? (You can make the parent elements non-expandable if you want.)

If you want to stick with the simple list, you can override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.

And maybe also override `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)`.

I have used the option of overriding `bindView()` to add a tag to a view and examine this later on. Maybe this would also work for you...

Comment: Can u give a complete solution for my problem using getView() method for differing the text style of Parent and child items....?